# Как добавить в данный код условие проверки числа на трёхзначность?

Tags: java

```
public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите трёхзначное число :");
        if (s.hasNextInt()){
            n = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Сумма цифр этого числа равна : " + ((n % 10) + ((n / 10) % 10) + ((n / 100) % 10)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Трехзначное число >= 100 и <= 999. Либо конвертни в строку и проверь длину.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Как именно добавить данное условие в код?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 5):

Если с минимальными правками вашего кода, то должно выйти что-то в духе:

```
class Task2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите трёхзначное число:");
        if (s.hasNextInt())
        {
            n = s.nextInt();
            if (isItThreeDigitNumber(n))
                System.out.println("Сумма цифр этого числа равна: " + ((n % 10) + ((n / 10) % 10) + (n / 100)));
            else
                System.out.println("Вы ввели не трехзначное число");
        }
    }

    static boolean isItThreeDigitNumber(int number)
    {
        return (100 <= number) && (number <= 999);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, к примеру, так.

```
int n = 4;
        String is = String.valueOf(n);
        int length = is.length();
   if(length == 3){...}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробные ответы.